# Help me write the sql to get distinct members

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql. I have a table called 'messages_received'. 
This is all messages for a particular user. What i would like to do is get a list of senders (from_member_id based on chrnological order.

In this case; the data would be like

```
59
10697
1451
3704
997
```

[image: Mysql data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(from_member_id) FROM messages_received ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this: (untested)

```
select max(id), from_member_id 
from messages_received 
group by from_member_id 
order by max(id) desc
```

this works in sqlite 3.5.9 but it seems that mysql doesn't like the `max` in `order by` so:

```
select max(id), from_member_id 
from messages_received 
group by from_member_id 
order by id desc
```

this also works in sqlite 3.5.9 but i think should work in mysql

Comment: #1111 - Invalid use of group function 

error i got from mYSQL

Answer (score 0):

```
select from_member_id, max(id) 
from messages_received
group by from_member_id
order by max(id) desc
```

Comment: #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT from_member_id FROM messages_received ORDER BY id DESC;
```